# RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I can not get this .htaccess work because there is some syntax error that I can't determinate. When I access the website, it prints a `Internal Server Error`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^201\.191\.20\.108 #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mantenimiento\.php$ #
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/mantenimiento.php [R=307,L] #
```

By the way, the following error is printed at error_log:

```
.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

The idea with this htaccess is redirect all request from `example.com` to `example.com/mantenimiento.php` in order to simulate a "maintenance mode" in the website

Comment: If you don't show the requested URL, it's impossible to guess the pattern for the conversion. Try to put an example of the URL entered in the browser address bar (Or requested by other means) and the substitution (real) URL you want.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA, post updated with the details. I though that the url was irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

Requested URL:

`http://example.com`

Substitution URL:

`http://example.com/mantenimiento.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^201\.191\.20\.108
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/mantenimiento.php [R=301,L]
```

The REQUEST_URI is not needed as there is NONE. To work, the REMOTE_ADDR cannot be the one in the pattern. Can use [307,L] too for a temporary redirection.

Comment: hmmm, what was the problem concretly? The `REQUEST_URI` or `#`?

Comment: The # starts a comment so it made no difference. On the other hand, the request URI was needed for the rewrite rule to execute, but the requested URL has no URI.

Comment: Than you so much for your help :) I really appreciate your time

Comment: You are welcome. Important to note that comments at the end of the line shouldn't be used as they now generate warnings that fill up the log files. In this case, that was not the case but is better to have that in mind.